# MPAndroidChart: Multi-line chart with filled area issue

Tags: legend, fill, mpandroidchart

I am now using the MPAndroidChart to draw line chart[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX0i2.png)

As you can see from the above screenshot, the color specified by me(showed in legend) is not the same as the finally filled in below the chart, is there any way to make sure that the different color will not mixed together?
Below is the code I used to draw two of the lines

```
    LineDataSet vlfDs = new LineDataSet(vlfValues, "VLF");
    vlfDs.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    vlfDs.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
    vlfDs.setDrawFilled(true);
    vlfDs.setDrawCircles(false);
    vlfDs.setLineWidth(0);
    vlfDs.setCircleRadius(4f);
    vlfDs.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    vlfDs.setFillColor(Color.YELLOW);
    vlfDs.setFillAlpha(100);

    LineDataSet lfDs = new LineDataSet(lfValues, "LF");
    lfDs.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
    lfDs.setDrawFilled(true);
    lfDs.setDrawCircles(false);
    lfDs.setLineWidth(0);
    lfDs.setCircleRadius(4f);
    lfDs.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    lfDs.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    lfDs.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
    lfDs.setFillAlpha(100);
    hrvLineData = new LineData(hfDs,lfDs,vlfDs, hrDs);
    hrvLineData.setValueTextSize(0);
    hrvLineData.setDrawValues(false);

    hrvChartView.setData(hrvLineData);

    hrvChartView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's turned out that I need to use setFillAlpha(255) instead of setFillAlpha(100)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something similar to the following solution which overrides the default `LineChartRenderer` and a uses a custom implementation of `IFillFormatter` to fill only the areas between the datasets.

[Android - Fill the color between two lines using MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342597/android-fill-the-color-between-two-lines-using-mpandroidchart/43452404#43452404)